# Scipy basinhopping custom step update and constrained looping

Tags: python, performance, scipy

I am searching for the global minimum of a certain function and trying to use its gradient (here same as Jacobin) to guide the step counter. However, my `x` is fix and so is my gradient. I am also trying to retrieve the fastest way possible the first `x` for which `f(x)<1`, therefore I am using a constraint.

- How can I update the `x` input and the Jacobin ?
- My `f(x)<1` is not being very effective, so is there any alternative to achieve my requirement?

This is my code (more or less):

```
class MyBounds(object):
    def __init__(self, xmax=[2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2], xmin=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ):
        self.xmax = np.array(xmax)
        self.xmin = np.array(xmin)

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        x    = kwargs["x_new"]
        tmax = bool(np.all(x <= self.xmax))
        tmin = bool(np.all(x >= self.xmin))
        return tmax and tmin

class MyTakeStep(object):
    def __init__(self, stepsize=1):
        self.stepsize = stepsize

    def compute_step(self, jacobi_matrix, x, i):
        if   jacobi_matrix[i] < 0: r = np.random.uniform(0,      2*np.pi-x[i])
        elif jacobi_matrix[i] > 0: r = np.random.uniform(0-x[i], 0)
        else                     : r = 0
        return r

    def __call__(self, x):
        print("ENTERING fROM CALL")
        print("THIS IS X: ", x)
        jacobi_matrix  = jacobian(x)
        print("x     : ", x)
        print("jacobi: ", jacobi_matrix)
        x[0] += self.compute_step(jacobi_matrix, x, 0)
        x[1] += self.compute_step(jacobi_matrix, x, 1)
        x[2] += self.compute_step(jacobi_matrix, x, 2)
        x[3] += self.compute_step(jacobi_matrix, x, 3)
        x[4] += self.compute_step(jacobi_matrix, x, 4)
        x[5] += self.compute_step(jacobi_matrix, x, 5)
        x[6] += self.compute_step(jacobi_matrix, x, 6)
        x[7] += self.compute_step(jacobi_matrix, x, 7)
        print("newx  : ", x)
        return x

def f(x):
    # objective function componenets
    result  = g1
    result += g2
    result += g3
    return result

def jacobian(x):
    print("input_list in Jacobi: ", x)

    # define full derivatives
    dG_dphi  = dg1_dphi + dg2_dphi + dg3_dphi
    dG_dr    = dg1_dr   + dg2_dr   + dg3_dr
    gradient = np.hstack((dG_dphi, dG_dr))

    print("G: ", gradient.shape, gradient, " \n")
    return gradient

def callback(x, f, accept):
    print("x: %65s | f: %5s | accept: %5s" % (str([round(e,3) for e in x]), str(round(f, 3)), accept))

def hopping_solver(min_f, min_x, input_excitation):
    # define bounds
    mybounds   = MyBounds()
    mytakestep = MyTakeStep()
    comb       = [deg2rad(phi) for phi in  input_excitation[:4]] + input_excitation[4:]
    print("comb: ", comb)
    min_f = 10
    tol   = 0
    cons = {'type':'ineq','fun': lambda x: 1-f(x)}
    k    = {"method":'Nelder-Mead', 'constraints': cons, 'jac': jacobian, 'tol': tol}
    optimal_c = optimize.basinhopping(f,
                                      x0               = comb,
                                      niter            = 1000000,
                                      T                = 8,
                                      stepsize         = 1,
                                      minimizer_kwargs = k,
                                      take_step        = mytakestep,
                                      accept_test      = mybounds,
                                      callback         = callback,
                                      interval         = 100000,
                                      disp             = True,
                                      niter_success    = None)
    print(optimal_c)
    min_x, min_f = optimal_c['x'], optimal_c['fun']
    comb         = min_x
    sol          = np.array(list([np.rad2deg(phi) for phi in list(optimal_c['x'][:4])]) + list(optimal_c['x'][4:]))
    min_x        = sol
    return min_x, min_f
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance.